# Preserve Maintenance Mode during Magento Core Deployment

Tags: maintenance, deploy

On remote webserver, i am deploying Magento core and modules through modman and Jenkins. During the deployment, a static maintenance page is shown which i enable and disable by the file `maintenance.flag`.

However, since i am also deploying the Magento core (and these files are removed on start of deployment), there is a (short) time frame when the Magento core files do not exist on the remote server. Consequently the file `maintenance.flag` does not work and the Magento maintenance page does not appear, but a PHP error page instead. For example:

> magento/app/Mage.php was not found

I want to avoid this behaviour.

What would you suggest in order to preserve a static maintenance page during the whole deployment process? Is it better to temporarily modify the `.htaccess` file to rewrite to a separate maintenance page, for example `maintenance.html`, that is not conntected with Magento core?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're deploying or modifying core you shouldn't rely on core. Ofcourse htaccess if a great solution. Other things i tend to do is create a static index.html page. By default the webserver serves index.html. change the name to --index.html or something when your done. Second i should do something with htaccess. like reroute it to my custom maintenance.html or something. It's basically the same idea.